# How to connect to SharePoint ( with Node.js) using OAuth with user context?

Tags: oauth, nodejs, sprequest

I created a Node.js App that connects to SharePoint(OnPremise and O365) and does all sorts of things.
The app uses [sp-request](https://github.com/s-KaiNet/sp-request) and [node-sp-auth](https://github.com/s-KaiNet/node-sp-auth) APIs for Basic Authentication (username, password),
and service calls
But I want to migrate to **OAuth** for security purposes.
I tried using [node-sp-auth](https://github.com/s-KaiNet/node-sp-auth) to connect using OAuth, but it only supports connection without user context, using (clientId,clientSecret), generated when registering the app on SharePoint.
The problem is this app is a mobile app destined for hundreds of users inside a company and every user has a different SharePoint account and permissions.
I also tried using [passport-sharepoint](https://github.com/QuePort/passport-sharepoint) but couldn't make work because the documentation is horrible (two bits of code full of mistakes and not functional).
Can anyone point me to the right direction ?

Comment: Unfortunately, by now `passport-sharepoint` is the only option I'm aware of. And that's true, samples look strange, and in general it looks like the project is not supported. Also it implements only low-trust scenario and doesn't work for high-trust. I have plans to implement **proper** authentication middleware for node and SharePoint, but this plans for next year..

Comment: BTW, `sp-request` supports all auth options from `node-sp-auth`, you can use oauth "clientId clientSecret" flow for `sp-request` too, but without user context (in SharePoint it called addin-only permissions, in oauth it's client credentials flow)

Comment: Ok thanks @Kai I guess I'll just stick with Basic Authentication for now, but if you do implement it, please post a response on this question. I'm sure there will be people interested in that.